Is it possible to have an anisotropic temperature to a Brownian motion?
Resolving the Langevin equation.
Tenperature is a scalar, is there a way to make it into vector?

Temperature can have a gradient, which is a vector. But temperature itself is a scalar.

Absolutely Not!
But don't let that stop you from musing:
For an ideal gas, the temperature is based on the average energy of an ideal gas, via:
$$ \frac 1 2 m\bar v^2 = \frac {3}{ 2} kT $$
so
$$ T = \frac {1} {3} \frac {m \bar v^2}{k} $$
Since a squared velocity is a scalar, there's really no way to back out a vector...
...but, we can make things more complicated, by considering a non-zero average velocity $\vec{\bar v}\rightarrow \bar v_i$. Abandoning all common sense, that allows us to construct the
(it's hard to say it): The (symmetric) temperature tensor:
$$ T_{ij} = \frac 1 3 \bar v_i \bar v_j $$
with the trace being the normal temperature:
$$ T = T_{ii} $$
Now if we pick the right coordinate ($\hat v = \hat z$), you can express that in spherical tensors with two non-zero components (scalar and longitudinal polarization):
$$ T_{ij} \rightarrow T^{(l=0,m=0)} + T^{(l=2,l=0)}$$
where the magnitude of each is proportion to temperature (by $\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}$ and $\frac 2 {\sqrt 3}$, respectively).
So, what we've done is turn normal temperature into an isotropic tensor, $T\delta_{ij}$, and a traceless velocity alignment "natural form$^1$" rank-2 tensor (proportional to $T$) looking like $v_iv_j - \frac 1 3 v^2\delta_{ij} $, and we've thrown out the velocity direction information.
So it wasn't a fruitful exercise. Also: I won't be accepting downvotes on this answer...consider it a belated April $1^{\rm st}$.
[1] A natural form rank-$N$ tensor (at least in 3-dimensions) is symmetric in all indices and traceless (on contraction of any-pair)...which takes the $3^N$ DoF down to $2N+1$....which is also the number of spherical harmonics with $l=N$. (For me: that was a Eureka moment regarding the geometric significance of tensors, which is a concern for many physics students).
